# padding string by adding char to the string

Tags: c, string, padding

I am trying to create a padding function that adds an underscore to a string. The string length should be 16, and if the string is less than 16 the function should add an underscore until the string length is 16, then return the padding string. If the string is more than 16, the padding function should ignore the characters and returned the first 16 characters of the string.

```c
char* padding(char* plaintext) {
    char ch = '_';
    size_t len = strlen(plaintext);
    size_t lench = 17 - len;
    char *p_text = malloc(len + 1 + 1);
    strcpy(p_text, plaintext);
    
    if (len < 17) {
        int i;
           
        for (i = lench; i < 16; i++) {
            p_text[i] = ch;
        }
    }
        
    // p_text[17] = '\0';
    return p_text;
}
     
int main() {
    char *key = "0123456789ABCDEF"; 
       
    while (1) {
        char plaintext[WIDTH + 1];
            
        printf("Enter a string: ");
        fgets(plaintext, WIDTH + 1, stdin);
           
        if (plaintext[0] == '\n' || plaintext[0] == '\r') 
            break;
            
        char* padded_plaintext = padding(plaintext);
        printf("padded plaintext = %s\n", padded_plaintext);
          
        printf("\n");
            
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

this code returns a weird result.

Comment: The space that you allocate for `p_text` should not depend on the input.  It should always be 17.

Comment: That you have a memory leak in a `while(1)` loop is a good demonstration of why this is a bad api.  You should probably have the caller pass in a buffer in which the padded string will be written rather than `malloc`ing space.  If you do `malloc`, make sure you `free`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a clean solution to this problem. Hopefully seeing this (and the accompanying explanation) helps.

```c
char *padded_string(char *src, int width, char ch) {
    char *dest = calloc(1, width + 1);

    strncpy(dest, src, width);

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        if (!dest[i]) {
            dest[i] = ch;
        }
    }

    return dest;
}
```

We provide ourselves a clean slate to work on by allocating `width + 1` bytes using `calloc`. Using `calloc` will ensure all bytes are set to `0`. When working with strings in C, they need to be null-terminated, so this is very useful.

We copy the contents of `src` into `dest`. Using `strncpy` ensures we don't get a buffer overflow if the source string is longer than the string we want to end up with.

Next we loop from `0`, `width` times. If the character in the destination string at `i` is a `'\0'` we'll insert the padding character at that index.

Now, because we used `calloc` and we allocated an extra byte beyond the character length we needed, the string is already null-terminated, we can simply return its pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The space that you allocate for p_text should not depend on the input. It should always be 17.  If `len + 1 + 1` < 16, then accessing `p_text[i]` will lead to undefined behavior for certain values of `i` that you are using.  You should replace:

```
char *p_text = malloc(len + 1 + 1);
```

with

```
char *p_text = malloc(17);
```

and check that `p_text` is not NULL before you write to it.

Also, the commented out `//p_text[17] = '\0';` is wrong. That should be

```
p_text[16] = '\0';
```